# Partially cached maps

Tags: wms, cache

Have anyone tried to set up a tilecache for a certain area of a map, leaving the areas outside of the tiles boundingbox to pure wms calls?

Background is I have a map where about 10% of it is accessed way more frequently than others and it would be good to have it cached but at the same time I can not cache the map as a whole due to space restrictions.

Can I do this in any tilecaching solution or do I have to split the map in two?

Comment: What server software are you currently using? Any preferences for caching software?

Comment: GeoServer with GeoWebCache can easily support this, but like geographika said you need to provide some details about your platform.

Comment: I was thinking of using Tilemill/MBTiles and the mapnik ogcserver toghether. The question was perhaps a bit vague